# How to prompt user for input in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a shell script in which I would like to prompt the user with a dialog box for inputs when the script is executed.

Example (after script has started):

```
"Enter the files you would like to install : "

user input : spreadsheet json diffTool

where $1 = spreadsheet, $2 = json, $3 = diffTool
```

then loop through each user input and do something like

```
for var in "$@"
do
    echo "input is : $var"
done
```

How would I go about doing this within my shell script?

Comment: I would pass the filenames as command line arguments. That's how more or less any UNIX tool works.

Comment: Consider [searching](https://www.google.com/webhp#q=bash+prompt+for+input) before asking. This exact question, and others like it, have been asked many, many times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shell script user prompt/input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/439390/608639).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read user input into a variable in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544359/how-to-read-user-input-into-a-variable-in-bash)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the `read` built-in available in `bash` and store the multiple user inputs into variables,

```
read -p "Enter the files you would like to install: " arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Give your inputs separated by space. For example, when running the above,

```
Enter the files you would like to install: spreadsheet json diffTool
```

now each of the above inputs are available in the variables `arg1`,`arg2` and `arg3`

---

The above part answers your question in way, you can enter the user input in one go space separated, but *if* you are interested in reading multiple in a loop, with *multiple prompts*, here is how you do it in `bash` shell. The logic below get user input until the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed,

```
#!/bin/bash

input="junk"
inputArray=()

while [ "$input" != "" ] 
do 
   read -p "Enter the files you would like to install: " input
   inputArray+=("$input")
done
```

Now all your user inputs are stored in the array `inputArray` which you can loop over to read the values. To print them all in one shot, do

```
printf "%s\n" "${inputArray[@]}"
```

Or a more proper loop would be to

```
for arg in "${inputArray[@]}"; do
    [ ! -z "$arg" ] && printf "%s\n" "$arg"
done
```

and access individual elements as `"${inputArray[0]}"`, `"${inputArray[1]}"` and so on.